# Post request with file_get_contents with arrays

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Im trying post a request via **file_get_contents** but i'm getting **error 500**, i'm doing this:

```
   $params = array("pid" => "000209", "main_widget_pid" => "000209");

    $array = array("method" => "bottomline","params" => $params);

    $url = 'http://example.com/test';
    $data = array('app_key' => '8948a6aa12a1a23Yzglj17QO91Geg', 'methods' => $array);

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );

$context  = stream_context_create($options); 
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

I believe the problem is in the structure of arrays. But I can not see the problem.

Can anyone give me a way?

Comment: `var_dump(http_build_query($data))` and compare to your API's docs.

Comment: It's the same. Requests are equal. If I make the request using the POSTMAN extension (Chrome) Im getting code 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this patch:

```
$data = array('app_key' => '8948a6aa12a1a23Yzglj17QO91Geg', 'methods' => $array);
$http_data = http_build_query($data);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
              . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $http_data,
    ),
);
```

Content-length header is important I guess.

Also $options looks like:

```
array (
  'http' => 
  array (
    'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
',
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => 'app_key=8948a6aa12a1a23Yzglj17QO91Geg&methods[method]=bottomline&methods[params][pid]=000209&methods[params][main_widget_pid]=000209',
  ),
)
```

Make sure, that it should be like this.

Error 500 in php means you got fatal exception in your script, after passing it this $options. Maybe you should debug what's wrong there...

Comment: why are you calling `strlen` on an array?